# Unit test case is failing to load webpack based js file having require to load css

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am using Webpack to bunlde my angular js code. However i am not able to write the mocha based unit test cases bcz gulp-mocha is failing to "require" css. Following are code snippet for details.

**Benefits.js angular js directive:**

```
var Utilities = require("./../../../../../utilities/Utilities");
var AppUtilities = require("./../../../../../utilities/AppUtilities");
require("./../../../../css/benefits.css");
module.exports = {
    getBenefits: function ($sce) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: require('html!./../../../../templates/page/Benefits.html'),
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                benefits: '=',
                productPageBenefits: '=',
                divider: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                //get benefit details as per given list of key
                scope.getBenefitsList = function (benefitKeyList, benefits) {
                    return OpensiteUtilities.getBenefitsList(benefitKeyList, benefits);
                };

            }
        };
    }
};
```

**Benefits_test.js is unit test case file:**

```
describe('The Benefits', function () {
    var Benefits = require('../../../../../../../../application/client-src/js/application/directives/productpage/Benefits.js');

    beforeEach(function () {

    });

    it('Should be an Object', function () {
        Benefits.should.be.a('Object');
        expect(Benefits).to.have.property('getBenefits');       
    });

});
```

I am gettign following error

```
/my/path/application/client-src/css/benefits.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @media (min-widt
                                                              ^
[16:18:49] { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL]
  name: 'SyntaxError',
  message: 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL',
  stack: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL\n    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)\n    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)\n    at require (module.js:380:17)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/path/application/client-src/js/application/directives/productpage/Benefits.js:9:1)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)\n    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)\n    at require (module.js:380:17)\n    at Suite.<anonymous> (/my/path/test/application/client-src/js/application/directives/productpage/Benefits_test.js:20:20)\n    at context.describe.context.context (/my/path/node_modules/jumpstart-engine/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:75:10)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/path/test/application/client-src/js/application/directives/productpage/Benefits_test.js:19:1)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-mocha' }
```

I understand its failing bcz gulp-mocha is not able to understand "css" file. How I can write the test cases? Do I have move "`require(./../benefits.css)`" outside of my directive code?

I want to keep all the dependencies in same directive code (using webpack). 
Please help

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to trigger Mocha through [mocha-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-loader) and set CSS to be loaded through [null-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/null-loader). That should fix the `require` issue you are encountering.

In case you want to solve it outside of Webpack you would need to patch `require` somehow. I expect you would want to use something like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) or [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) in that case.